# C++ covariance unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance

I got an unexpected result which I couldn't explain myself so far.

Although two times an object of the same class `BASIC2` (inheriting from `BASIC1`) is generated a different message is generated when using the friend `operator<<` on the generated object.

See code below

I let `D` (object of a class `Derived` which inherits from `Base`) generate an object of class `BASIC2` and call it's friend `operator<<`. This produces the expected message `"BASIC2 object"`.

I let `B` generate an object of class `BASIC1` and call its friend `operator<<`. This outputs `"BASIC1 object"` as I expected.

Then I use virtual inheritance to let `B2` (`Base* B2 = &D;`) generate an object of `BASIC2`. I follow the code flow in the debugger (Visual Studio 2010) and this correctly generates an object of `BASIC2`. However, the friend `operator<<` is not called on the `BASIC2` object, but uses the friend `operator<<` from class `BASIC1` (and hence outputs `"BASIC1 object"`).

Note also I do want `BASIC2` to inherit from `BASIC1` as I want to exploit the covariance behavior.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Base B;
    Derived D;
    Base* B2 = &D;
    std::cout << *D.generate(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *B.generate(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(B2->generate(0)) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

The output is:

```
BASIC2 object
BASIC1 object
BASIC1 object
```

```
class BASIC1 {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BASIC1& basic) {
    os << "BASIC1 object";
    return os;
    }
};

class BASIC2 : public BASIC1 {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BASIC2& basic) {
    os << "BASIC2 object";
    return os;
    }
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual BASIC1* generate(double num) const {
    return new BASIC1();
    }
protected:
private:
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual BASIC2* generate(double num) const override {
    return new BASIC2();
    }
protected:
private:
};
```

Comment: Well the static type of `B2` is `Base`, so the function seen by the compiler is `BASIC1* Base::generate(double)` (dynamic dispatch calls `Derived::generate`). The return type is `BASIC1*`, though. And the `operator<<` is selected based on the static type of the expression `*(B2->generate(0))`.

Comment: @dyp: I.e. this `operator<<` isn't "`virtual`".

Comment: Runtime/dynamic dispatch is only done on member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selection of operator<< is based on static type of your object known during compilation time. To achieve what you want do not define two operator<< function, but one only in BASIC1:

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BASIC1& basic) {
      Write(os);
      return os;
    }
```

and define virtual function Write in both BASIC1 and BASIC2 to do what you want:

```
virtual void Write(std::ostream& os) const {
   os << "BASIC1 object";
}
```

Comment: One should use: virtual void Write(std::ostream& os) const {
   os << "BASIC1 object";
} as I pass a const Basic& object

Comment: Yes it is better to enforce constness wherever possible.

Comment: write must be given a const method qualifier otherwise (it won't compile) you have to guarantee that the const object you pass into operator<< won't be modified by write..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! For me the end conclusion of my question is: If you call friend operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& object) on an object in which the object is generated through dynamic dispatching. You need to use virtual functions in your operator<< to allow for dynamic dispatching of the operator<<.